# Is $W_0^{1,p}$ weakly closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ weakly closed? $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$  with respect to the norm of $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, and I've been trying to figure out if it is true that if we have a sequence $u_n\in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ that converges weakly to $u\in W^{1,p}$ then $u\in W_0^{1,p}$. (By weak convergence in $W^{1,p}$ I mean weak convergence in $L^p$ of both $u_n$ and $\nabla u_n$)

The only thing I could think of was to approximate each $u_n$ with a sequence $(u_n^k)_k\in C_0^{\infty}$. Then by the Sobolev embedding theorems we have that weak convergence of $\nabla u_n$ in $L^p$ implies strong convergence of $u_n$ in $L^p$, so it should be possible to approximate $u$ with $C_0^{\infty}$ functions in the $L^p$ norm. But what about the derivatives?
I hope I have not been too confusing. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this true trivially? Weak convergence is defined as follows: Given $u_n, u\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$, we say that $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ ($u_n$ converges weakly to $u$), if $\int u_n \varphi \to \int u\varphi$ for every test function $\varphi$... So the limit is an element of your space *by definition*. Or do you have an alternative definition?

Comment: I suppose $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$  with respect to the $\color{red}{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}$ norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $C\subset E$ be a convex set.

Theorem: $C$ is weakly closed if and only if $C$ is strong closed (closed in the norm topology).

For the proof you can take a look in the book of [Brezis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134), Theorem 3.7.

Comment: How do we know $W_0^{1,p}$ is convex? Thank you.

Comment: I found the trick: every subspace of a normed space is convex, and the closure of a subspace is again convex.

Comment: Tomás, you've been most helpful! Your answer totally resolved my doubts in other questions! Thank you very much, really.